# Read image in a Vaadin 7.6 and Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I'm trying code a project using Vaadin 7.6 and Spring Boot. I'd like to display in ma page an Image. For that, I've read the book of Vaadin in which I've found:

```
 // Find the application directory
 String basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent()
                           .getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 // Image as a file resource
 FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(basepath + "/WEB-INF/images/image.png"));
 // Show the image in the application
Image image = new Image("Image from file", resource);
```

But there's a problem. With Spring boot, there isn't any WEB-INF folder. I've got those folder:

- resources
- resources/static
- resources/templates

I've created the directory `resources/static/images` and I've saved an image. After, I've tried a code like that:

```
String basePath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(basePath + "/images/telecaster.jpg"));
Image telecaster = new Image("Telecaster", resource);
```

But when I try ma page I've got the exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/nm/kv40tr650llcmk6rssnxzt900000gn/T/tomcat-docbase.5908407388863057264.8080/images/telecaster.jpg (No such file or directory). 
My image is well deployed because when I try the URL http://localhost:8080/images/telecaster.jpg, I get the image.

How can I access images (and any file types) from my Vaadin source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.
I create the directory `src/main/WEB-INF/images` and I define the folder WEB-INF as a resources folder.

After, I write a classic code about resource:

```
    String imagePath = IdeaxBoxUI.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/telecaster.jpg").getPath();
    FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(imagePath));
    Image telecaster = new Image("Telecaster", resource);
```

Comment: Did you try the other answer's suggestion? Because ThemeResource is the preferred way to do.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can load image via ThemeResource class. The class by default looks for resources under standard VAADIN/themes/{themeName} directory. Following is a code example:

```
new ThemeResource("images/admin-user.jpg")
```

where images is a directory under VAADIN/themes/{themeName} directory.